# Parse causes "SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed"

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Using parse.com, I'd like to fetch new messages from the server and pin them locally. I'm on Android 5.0.1 and Parse-1.8.1.

```
@Override
public void fetchMessagesFromServer(final Conversation conversation, Date newerThanDate, final Callback<List<Message>> callback) {
  ParseQuery<Message> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
  parseQuery.whereEqualTo(Message.CONVERSATION, conversation);
  parseQuery.whereGreaterThan(Message.CREATED_AT, newerThanDate);
  parseQuery.orderByAscending(Message.CREATED_AT);
  parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Message>() {
    @Override
    public void done(final List<Message> messages, ParseException e) {
      if (e != null) {
        callback.error(e);
      } else {
        Message.pinAllInBackground(conversation.getObjectId(), messages, new SaveCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
              callback.error(e);
            } else {
              callback.success(messages);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Fetching works as expected, I get 6 `Message` objects, all having an objecId. But pinning them using `Message.pinAllInBackground(String name, List<Message> objects, SaveCallback saveCallback)`  fails with `com.parse.ParseException: bolts.AggregateException: There were 6 exceptions.`

`AggregateException.causes` contains 6 equal exceptions:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: ParseObjects.className, ParseObjects.objectId (code 2067)
```

While I understand that an unique constraint consisting of className and objectId fails, I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Inspecting all 6 Message objects show that all objectIds are different. Does anyone see a problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: Have you enabled local data store while initializing parse library?

Comment: Yes it's enabled and working.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No sorry, just checked my code and saw that I commented out the `pinAllInBackground()` and added a link to this issue. And since parse.com was announced to die, I moved away.